# Oracle sysdate is not equal to a stored date

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause, precision, sysdate

Database: **Oracle**

Simplified version:

Table **T** has a column: **D** ( DATE type )

Now the table is empty.

```
INSERT INTO T
    (D) VALUES (sysdate);
```

Now the table has one row containing 22-AUG-14.

**Why** is the following WHERE clause **false** ?

```
SELECT * FROM T
    WHERE D = sysdate;
```

=> **0 rows**

The following query works:

```
SELECT * FROM T
    WHERE TO_CHAR(D, 'DD/MM/YYYY') = TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

=> 1 row

I suppose that there is a "lost of precision" related to time (similar to double & int), but why is it possible ? Because both types are DATE.

- sysdate returns a DATE according to http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions172.htm

Comment: Do a `SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL` and it will show you the issue.

Comment: This is what I tried, but SQL Developer had only DD-MON-RR for Date Format, and this is why I couldn't see the time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sysdate` also includes time, so this query will always fail to return any rows as time will keep changing

```
SELECT * FROM T
    WHERE D = sysdate;
```

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM T
    WHERE trunc(D) = trunc(sysdate);
```

Comment: Thank you!
I thought that my DATE doesn't contain time because my SQL Developer didn't show the whole format (only DD-MON-RR). I changed to DD-MON-RR HH:MI:SS and now it's very clear. (NLS > Date Format)